# Debugging AngularJS injection error: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:

Tags: angularjs

I am injecting an Angular constant into a controller.  I had already had a constant that was working just fine.  However, when I added this constant, I started getting the Unknown provider message on it.

I'm sure I've left something undone, but I'm not seeing it.  Are there any good suggestions on how to best track this down?

The error message:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: COLUMN_DEFAULTProvider <- COLUMN_DEFAULT <- Dashboard
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=COLUMN_DEFAULTProvider%20%3C-%20COLUMN_DEFAULT%20%3C-%20Dashboard
at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:63:12)
at http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4015:19
at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4162:39)
at http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4020:45
at getService (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4162:39)
at invoke (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4194:13)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:4211:27)
at http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:8501:28
at link (http://localhost:56263/scripts/angular-route.js:975:26)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:56263/Scripts/angular.js:8258:9) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

I'm using some code from [github](https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-highcharts) to wrap highcharts in Angular.  What I wanted to do was to add another chart type.  The chart constant sets some default settings:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('frapontillo.highcharts.constants')

  /**
   * @ngdoc object
   * @name frapontillo.highcharts.constants.constant:COLUMN_DEFAULT
   *
   * @description
   * Default configuration for a solid gauge type of chart.
   *
   * @return {object} COLUMN_DEFAULT Column configuration defaults.
   */
  .constant('COLUMN_DEFAULT', {
      name: 'column',
      options: {
          chart: {
              type: 'column',
              renderTo: this.ID,
              borderWidth: 0,
              backgroundColor: null,
              spacing: [10, 10, 10, 10]
          },
          exporting: {
              enabled: false
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          credits: {
              enabled: false
          },
          title: {
              text: ''
          },
          xAxis: {
              labels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  style: {
                      font: 'Arial',
                      fontSize: '10px',
                      fontWeight: 'normal',
                      zIndex: -100
                  },
                  useHTML: true,
              },
              tickWidth: 0.5,
              tickLength: 3,
              type: "category",
          },
          yAxis: {
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              borderWidth: 0,
              gridLineWidth: 0,
              minorGridLineWidth: 0,
              dataLabels: {
                  enabled: false
              },
              labels: {
                  enabled: true,
                  format: '{value}%'
              },
              title: {
                  text: '',
              },
              plotBands: ConfigMgr.getChartPlotBands()
          },
          plotOptions: {
              column: {
                  pointPadding: 0.2,
                  borderWidth: 0
              },
          },
          tooltip: {
              enabled: false,
              shared: true,
              useHTML: true,
          },
      }
  })
    .config(configure);

configure.$inject = ['$chartDefaultsProvider', 'COLUMN_DEFAULT'];

function configure($chartDefaultsProvider, COLUMN_DEFAULT) {
    $chartDefaultsProvider.addDefault(COLUMN_DEFAULT.name, COLUMN_DEFAULT.options);
}
});
```

This constant is loaded in the module definition:

```
angular.module('frapontillo.highcharts.directives',     ['frapontillo.highcharts.providers']);

angular.module('frapontillo.highcharts.constants', ['frapontillo.highcharts.providers']);

angular.module('frapontillo.highcharts.providers', []);

angular.module('frapontillo.highcharts', ['frapontillo.highcharts.directives', 'frapontillo.highcharts.constants',  'frapontillo.highcharts.providers'
]);
```

Finally in my app.core.js, I have:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app.core', [
    // App blocks
    'blocks.logger',
    'frapontillo.highcharts'


    // 3rd Party Modules

]);
})();
```

My abbreviated controller looks like:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Dashboard', dashboard);

dashboard.$inject = ['$scope', 'logger', 'dashboarddata', 'SOLIDGAUGE_DEFAULT', 'COLUMN_DEFAULT'];

function dashboard($scope, logger, dashboarddata, SOLIDGAUGE_DEFAULT, COLUMN_DEFAULT) {
})();
```

app.js:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('app', [
    // Angular modules 
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngRoute',

    // Custom modules 

    // 3rd Party Modules
    'app.core',
    'app.layout',
    'app.services'
])

.config(configure)
.run(['$route', '$rootScope', '$q',
    function ($route, $rootScope, $q) {
        // Include $route to kick start the router.
        //breeze.core.extendQ($rootScope, $q);
        //routemediator.setRoutingHandlers();
    }]);

configure.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
/**
* Setup routes
* @param $routeProvider Angular route component
* @param $locationProvider Angular location component
*/
function configure($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: "Home/Dashboard",
            controller: "Dashboard",
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })
    .otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/home/Index'
        });
}
})();
```

Now I only added this one constant (SOLIDGAUGE_DEFAULT existed previously), all other parts of this frapontillo.highcharts module were working ok before.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: Suggestion: Asking people to find the bug, but not providing any code or error message won't lead you anywhere. Sigh.

Comment: @JB Nizet: I'm not asking anyone to find the bug.  I'm asking if there is something I can examine that would help me determine where the issue is.  I run into this error from time to time and it usually is something like forgetting to put a .js file in a script tag to download it or something like that.  What I want, is a way of determining where the breakdown is.

Comment: @Fals: It is a constant of my own.

Comment: @MikeWitt we can't help you if you don't provide any code or exemple of code that generate the issue,

Comment: Put yourself into angular and the browser's shoes. What is needed for this constant to be correctly injected? Then check if everything is there: the JS file is in the html, the constant is declared. There is no typo. The module is loaded, etc. That's how you debug basically everything.

Comment: > Are there any good suggestions on how to best track this down?
Sure. Please, post full error messages, not truncated. The answer for such question would be 'something went wrong with injection, you need to fix something'.

Comment: @estus, I'll update to give the full error message.  I left it out because it seemed mostly useless (giving the name of my constant).  I might go back and put the code in (since everyone is so interested :) ).  I'll have to cleanse it of proprietary stuff first.

Comment: Is the JS file containing the constant definition inside a script in the HTML page? Can you find it in the Sources tab of your browser dev tools?

Comment: Dependencies look fine to me, no typos. What is `ConfigMgr`, is it available at function scope? Are you certain there were no other errors thrown? If they keep the constant from declaration, that would explain a lot.

Comment: You define your module as `app.core` but then use it as `app`. Is this just a typo issue?

Comment: @estus - ConfigMgr is something I still need to create, but I've commented all that stuff out before and still get the same error.  The error comes on injected the COLUMN_DEFAULT into the controller.  If I remove that, no error.

Comment: @floribon - There is an "app" module but I didn't include that file.  I'll add it.

Comment: @JB Nizet: The constants file is in it's own js file and I can find it in the sources of the browser tools window.

Comment: So, you have your answer: you forgot to add a script for this file in your html file. Or you included a script pointing to a wrong location.

Comment: @JB Nizet, when I said I was going to add the app module, I meant to the original question.  It was already in my project I just forgot it earlier.  Problem still not solved.  I tried adding another constant that had nothing to it and I still got the same problem.  I tried adding a factory and that worked.  Still confused.